# How to check format of a string before feeding it to Convert.DateTime()

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq

I have a LINQ query

```
rpt = base.Session.QueryOver<Report>(() => rptAlias).
                                  JoinAlias(() => rptAlias.ReportStatus, () => statusAlias).
                                  JoinAlias(() => rptAlias.Patient, () => patAlias).Left.JoinAlias(() => rptAlias.SoapNotes, () => soapAlias).
                                  JoinAlias(() => patAlias.User, () => usrAlias).Where
                                  (() => (usrAlias.FirstName.IsLike(data, MatchMode.Anywhere)
                                  || usrAlias.LastName.IsLike(data, MatchMode.Anywhere) || usrAlias.Email.IsLike(data, MatchMode.Anywhere) || (patAlias.DateOfBirth.Date)==(Convert.ToDateTime(data)) ||
                                 (patAlias.MedNexusId.IsLike(data, MatchMode.Anywhere) || patAlias.MedNexusId == null)) && usrAlias.IsDeleted == false
                                  && rptAlias.IsDeleted == false && rptAlias.IsNormal.IsIn(lstIsNormal)
                                  && statusAlias.Id.IsIn(lstSearch)
                                  )
                                  .OrderBy(() => usrAlias.LastName).Desc.OrderBy(() => rptAlias.Id).Asc
                                 .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
                                 .Take(pageSize)
                                 .List<Report>();
```

here u must have noticed a variable data,now the problem is it contains whatever we enter in a text box in the view so it may contain
1.First Name
2.Last Name
3.Id
4.Email Id
5.Date of birth

or the worst case is it can be null as well so when it contains date of birth then all is well but in other cases the data is not in proper format to be passed as a parameter to `Convert.ToDateTime` and i get exception.

So my question is How can I check beforehand that data is in correct format or not?

Comment: You might also need to consider how to treat 09/05/2014 and 05/09/2014. They both are valid, but different in different cultures.

Comment: "here u must have noticed a variable data" - well only just, because it's surrounded by a massive amount of irrelevant code. It's not clear where the query is relevant at all, to be honest. If you're *just* interested in parsing the value, that's got nothing to do with the code you've given, really.

Comment: Look the thing is there is a single text box and it that you can search any of the above mentioned five things and data is just a variable.

Comment: exactly @Yahya but we need only mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    DateTime myDt;
    bool parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(date,"d/M/yyyy",null,out myDt);
    if(parsed) DoSomething;
```

Actually DateTime.TryParseExact works on taking a Date template which u see here as "d/M/yyyy" and try to match the string to be exact like that "12/03/1902" for example . Find more here :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also You can use DateTime.TryParse

Comment: if the variable contains some name suppose "Ramy" then will it work?

Comment: no , it will return false , so you will send a warning saying it's not a date or something

Comment: but it will not serve my purpose the same variable can have 5 values in 5 conditions and all are valid i.e it may be "20123","Ramy","Mohamed","Ramy@Mohamed.com" or "13/05/2014" or it may be blank too

Comment: this method returns true only if the string matches the template you are providing

Comment: here are a lot of templates to try : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Comment: can I use this                                                       if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"MM/dd/YYYY")) {
  // It's a match
}

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) .

You will need to parse the string before creating the query, which is A Good Thing - make sure your input is correct first, then process it.

Comment: I don't need to parse the string what i need is just checking if the string is in correct format or not if not then i will have another code in else

Comment: DateTime.TryParse (or TryParseExact) is the way to see if the string is in the correct format.

Comment: It doesn't do anything with the string, it writes a DateTime to an output argument. You can ignore that.